# Как правильно расставить запятые? Возникла проблема

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> Беспричинно хвалил и ругал и тем самым вносил сумятицу в нашу общую
> жизнь в наше тихое гнездо.

Answer (score 2):

*Беспричинно (хвалил и ругал) и **тем самым** вносил сумятицу в нашу общую жизнь, в наше тихое гнездо.*

Этот случай рассматривается в правилах Розенталя (пункт 8)

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=101#pp101

8. Если два однородных члена предложения, соединенные союзом И, образуют **тесно связанную по смыслу пару**, соединенную союзом И с третьим однородным членом, **запятая не ставится:** *Вода давно сбыла в Тереке и быстро сбегала и сохла по канавам* (Л. Т.) — парная группа сбегала и сохла с общим второстепенным членом по канавам, оба глагола несовершенного вида, в отличие от глагола-сказуемого совершенного вида сбыла; *Задолго до рассвета Ильинична затопила печь и к утру уже выпекла хлеб и насушила две сумы сухарей* (Ш.) — парная группа выпекла и насушила с общим обстоятельством времени к утру;

В приведенном предложении **первый союз И** соединяет близкие по смыслу сказуемые (хвалил и ругал), а третье сказуемое присоединяется к ним **вторым союзом И**, причем это сказуемое имеет **собственный  второстепенный член** "тем самым".

Поэтому здесь **нет повторяющегося союза И...И**, у каждого союза своя функция. Соответственно, запятая не ставится.

Answer (score 0):

**Беспричинно хвалил и ругал и тем самым вносил сумятицу в нашу общую жизнь, в наше тихое гнездо.**
Запятые в части *"...хвалил и ругал и тем самым вносил..."* не нужны, соответствующее правило [здесь](http://orthographia.ru/punctum.php?paragraph=pg28.php).

Comment: Извините пожалуйста, но я так и не понял, как связано правило с постановкой запятой в моем примере, не могли бы вы подробнее разъяснить, если вас не затруднит?

Comment: @user201362 у вас "хвалил и ругал" — пара, тесно связанная по смыслу. Она воспринимается как единый член, однородный члену "вносил (сумятицу)". По ссылке есть схожий пример: "...она со слезами несколько раз перечитывала [письмо] и мяла и комкала" — "мяла и комкала" воспринимается как единый член, однородный члену "перечитывала". Поэтому запятая не нужна, хотя случай похож на повторяющиеся союзы.

Comment: Большое спасибо!